# How can compare two integer with only using ==, + and recursion?

Tags: algorithms

Here is the original question from MIT lecture notes :

> Write a Spy procedure that takes two positive integers as input and returns True if the first is greater than the second. Use only the primitive functions = and + and recursion.

I haven't figure out anyway to compare two number with these requirements. Spy is just fictional language created by lecturer for educational purpose. So you can do it with another language or just pseudocode.

Edit

Why are you down voting ? I just didn't understand question and want to know whether this is possible or not.

Comment: I forgot to mention '=' operator is comparison of two number in Spy. So you can use if/else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since they are integers and you can use addition, you can increment one until one number is equal to the other.  Let's say you're comparing 4 and 7 to see the relationship.

```
N   M   N'  M'
4 | 7
4 | 7 | 5 | 8
4 | 7 | 6 | 9
4 | 7 | 7 | 10
```

Each row increments N' and M' by one (+1) from the last iteration.

You can see that on the last row, N' == M, i.e. the incremented N equals the original M.   Thus, we have discovered that N < M (as N can be incremented to become M).

If the inputs we reversed (7,4 instead of 4,7), we would find that eventually M' == N, which would tell us that N > M.

(You should check for N == M before attempting incremental matches.)

---

Next, all you have to do is implement using recursion...

Comment: So we should pass original arguments to method every time. Procedure might be something like this `boolean greater(x,y,xp,yp)`. And we will call it like this `greater(4,7,4,7)`

Comment: Yes, that is one approach.  I think there are others, e.g. a single counter that starts at 1 and increments, and it is use to compare x + N == y  (telling us x < y) vs. x == y + N (telling us x > y).  The issue is that one of the comparisons will never match, so we should interleave the checking of both.

Comment: Looks like your approach is better. But question explicitly states that procedure should take two arguments.

Comment: Often recursive functions require helpers to provide a nice interface. So there's a function that takes two args, and turns around and calls the true recursive function with more parameters (setting the initial values of them).  This is quite common in industry, though it is quite conceivable that you're not allowed helper functions/wrappers in the exercise.

Comment: Ok, are you allowed to add -1? If so, then add -1 to both, and whichever gets to zero first is the smaller -- this can be done with two args in a recursive function that does not use helpers.

Comment: I got your point and looks like there is no way to done this like in description.

Comment: Looks like SPY supports constants like -1, so you might be allowed add -1, and use the first to zero approach.

Answer (score -1):

That kind of question is just ridiculous. It has no educational value whatsoever, and should never turn up in any lecture notes. I cannot actually solve it, because my brain refuses to engage when confronted with that kind of pointless question.

Oh well.

```
bool brainfart (int x, int y) {
    return x == y ? false : x == INT_MAX ? true : brainfart (x+1, y);
}
```

Comment: Here is original source [link](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-01sc-introduction-to-electrical-engineering-and-computer-science-i-spring-2011/unit-1-software-engineering/object-oriented-programming/MIT6_01SCS11_chap03.pdf), page   91, exercise 3.17.

Comment: @gnasher  , Its silly but this question can serve as a nice exercise. Just look at your answer to understand why

Comment: @ShaiAharoni There's nothing nice about it. Compare to the good solution: bool (isEqual) (int x, int y) { return x == y; } Then change from int to int64_t.